# How to write txt file?

Tags: wp-remote-get

I have 2 functions about the wp_remote_get.

I wanna write all data ( functions output ) into the txt file ? How to ?

**the functions;**

```
// facebook
function hayransayisi(){
         $fb_id = '206938902665808';
         $count = get_transient('fan_count');
    if ($count !== false) return $count;
         $count = 0;
         $data = wp_remote_get('http://api.facebook.com/restserver.php?method=facebook.fql.query&query=SELECT%20fan_count%20FROM%20page%20WHERE%20page_id='.$fb_id.'');
   if (is_wp_error($data)) {
         return 'yok öylesi!!!';
   }else{
         $count = strip_tags($data[body]);
   }
set_transient('fan_count', $count, 60*60*24); // 24 hour cache
return $count;
}
```

The twitter function ;

```
// Twitter
function rarst_twitter_user( $username, $field, $display = false ) {
$interval = 3600;
$cache = get_option('rarst_twitter_user');
$url = 'http://api.twitter.com/1/users/show.json?screen_name='.urlencode($username);

if ( false == $cache )
$cache = array();

if ( !isset( $cache[$username][$field] ) ) {
$cache[$username][$field] = NULL;
$cache[$username]['lastcheck'] = 0;
}

if( $cache[$username]['lastcheck'] < (time()-$interval) ) {

static $memorycache;

if ( isset($memorycache[$username]) ) {
$data = $memorycache[$username];
}
else {
$result = wp_remote_retrieve_body(wp_remote_request($url));
$data = json_decode( $result );
if ( is_object($data) )
$memorycache[$username] = $data;
}

if ( is_object($data) ) {
foreach ($cache[$username] as $key => $value)
if( isset($data->$key) )
$cache[$username][$key] = $data->$key;

$cache[$username]['lastcheck'] = time();
}
else {
$cache[$username]['lastcheck'] = time()+60;
}

update_option( 'rarst_twitter_user', $cache );
}

if ( false != $display )
echo $cache[$username][$field];
return $cache[$username][$field];
}
```

anyone help ?
thanks.

Comment: "_I have 2 functions about the wp_remote_get_" ... `update_option( 'rarst_twitter_user', $cache );` ... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How does these functions relate to writing file? Do you want to write to file in general or modify functions to accomplish that?

Simple approach - do it with PHP, for example with [`file_put_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php). However between different hosting configurations this is not always reliable. Actually workflows in WP make real effort to not write any more files than really necessary - most of things go into database.

Complex and more reliable approach - [Filesystem API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Filesystem_API).

I'd suggest considering database for storage first.